Can not find file .env on the file system
This is my project path in project
com.bor.lockSysytem\
    │       ├── WEB-INF\
    │       │   ├── web.xml
    │       │   └── .env   

 import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;
     public interface IConstant {   
        Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().directory("WEB-INF").filename(".env").load(); 
        public static final String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = dotenv.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"); 
}

This output when cant not file
Suppressed: io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.DotenvException: Could not find WEB-INF\.env on the file system (working directory: D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.100\bin)
        
            

I dont know why I cant take the path and get variable enviroment by this code , I use dotenv-java-2.3.2.jar and dont work with pom.xml
But when i dont set file .env in WEB-INF and set this file in folder bin of  folder apache-tomcat
and use code Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().directory(".") .filename(".env").load();  and it can work , but I think i should not set in folder bin . So I hope I can solver that

Please review your question and have again a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Especially the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example part.


.env file , default war path is WEB-INF/classes/.env.
not WEB-INF/.env

com.bor.lockSysytem
...
└── WEB-INF
    ├── web.xml
    └── classes
       ├── .env    
       └── com
           └── bor
               ├── ....
               └── ....

IConstant.java
public interface IConstant {   

  //Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().directory("WEB-INF").filename(".env").load(); 
  Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.load();
  
  public static final String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = dotenv.get("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"); 
}


this is output : Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified

(1) Deal with one problem at a time. (2) You can use System.out.println("IConstant.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = " + IConstant.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID); to print out the value obtained through .env. If it is obtained The value you set means that the problem you asked has been solved.

(3) The current error message is another problem. You need to provide more details. You can't guess it just by looking at "Target host is not specified" What is the reason? Because the original error message should show which method or line of which class the error occurred. So you have to find the corresponding class based on the error message.
